# Invalidate form input that contains HTML

Tags: python, validation, google-app-engine

I'm using GoogleAppEngine with Python runtime and I have a very simple contact form. How do I invalidate submissions where a field contains HTML?

Comment: you should also be looking out for SQL syntax. SQL injection is a very common issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, use the input from the field and populate it into a sting then you can remove the HTML tags from that string like so:

This function can strip the HTML for you and is nice, as it requires only the Python stdlib:

On Python 2

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class MLStripper(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        self.reset()
        self.fed = []
    def handle_data(self, d):
        self.fed.append(d)
    def get_data(self):
        return ''.join(self.fed)

def strip_tags(html):
    s = MLStripper()
    s.feed(html)
    return s.get_data()
```

For Python 3

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser

    class MLStripper(HTMLParser):
        def __init__(self):
        self.reset()
        self.strict = False
        self.convert_charrefs= True
        self.fed = []
    def handle_data(self, d):
        self.fed.append(d)
    def get_data(self):
        return ''.join(self.fed)

def strip_tags(html):
    s = MLStripper()
    s.feed(html)
    return s.get_data()
```

Another way is to intersect start and end tags found by attempting to parse the text as HTML and intersecting this set with a known set of acceptable HTML elements.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function

from HTMLParser import HTMLParser


from html5lib.sanitizer import HTMLSanitizerMixin


class TestHTMLParser(HTMLParser):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.elements = set()

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        self.elements.add(tag)

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        self.elements.add(tag)


def is_html(text):
    elements = set(HTMLSanitizerMixin.acceptable_elements)

    parser = TestHTMLParser()
    parser.feed(text)

    return True if parser.elements.intersection(elements) else False


print(is_html("foo bar"))
print(is_html("<p>Hello World!</p>"))
print(is_html("<html><head><title>Title</title></head><body><p>Hello!</p></body></html>"))  # noqa
```

Output:

```
$ python foo.py
False
True
True
```

You can then validate the submission according to the true/false value returned. You will have to implement you own logic and process of course

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [wtforms](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms). It is a great tool for validating forms and it works with GAE/P.

With wtforms, you can write custom validators for form inputs.  One very over-inclusive but potentially usable validator would be to reject form inputs that have `<` or `>` in them.